# I upgraded Unity 2019 to Unity 2021.3.22f1 and I faced multiple error CS0433. How do I resolve it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Good Day
I upgraded Unity 2019 to Unity 2021.3.22f1 and I faced multiple error CS0433. Those are the errors:

```
a. Library/PackageCache/com.unity.purchasing@4.7.0/Runtime/WinRTStub/Factory.cs(15,23): error CS0433: The type 'IWindowsIAP' exists in both 'UnityEngine.Purchasing.WinRTCore, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'winrt, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

b. Library/PackageCache/com.unity.purchasing@4.7.0/Runtime/SecurityStub/GooglePlayReceipt.cs(37,38): error CS0433: The type 'IPurchaseReceipt' exists in both 'Security, Version=1.0.7807.33496, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'UnityEngine.Purchasing.SecurityCore, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

c. Library/PackageCache/com.unity.purchasing@4.7.0/Runtime/SecurityStub/CrossPlatformValidator.cs(43,16): error CS0433: The type 'IPurchaseReceipt' exists in both 'Security, Version=1.0.7807.33496, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'UnityEngine.Purchasing.SecurityCore, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

d. Library/PackageCache/com.unity.purchasing@4.7.0/Runtime/SecurityStub/AppleValidator.cs(53,16): error CS0433: The type 'AppleReceipt' exists in both 'Security, Version=1.0.7807.33496, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'UnityEngine.Purchasing.SecurityCore, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

e. Library/PackageCache/com.unity.purchasing@4.7.0/Runtime/SecurityStub/AppleValidator.cs(33,16): error CS0433: The type 'AppleReceipt' exists in both 'Security, Version=1.0.7807.33496, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'UnityEngine.Purchasing.SecurityCore, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
```

I found the duplicated files but it refuses to be deleted
I can just modify them
I need your help to resolve those issue
Kind Regards,

I tried to delete those files and it didn't work.
I expect to know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling the packages and installing newer versions? Modules from the repositories (github or the PM) get deprecated as Unity evolves and you need newer versions that are compatible with the current engine. In your case, we're talking about 2 generations apart, not just a few versions.

Comment: Yes I did try removing the packages, restarting Unity and then installing them again, restarting Unity again. Nothing changes

Answer (score 0):

When you are installing the Unity purchasing package in newer versions of Unity, there is the update guide right in the package window. Did you check it?

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your kind help. All those methods are not applying because: 1. IAPProductCatalog.json and BillingMode.json cannot be found. 2. AppleTangle.cs and GooglePlayTangle.cs cannot be found. 3. Should I delete the entire folder?

Comment: What are these files? As I didn't export builds to mobile, I can't tell. Are they part of the packages or are they generated for **YOUR** project? If they are part of your project, make a backup, delete them and see the new way to regenerate them (if needed).

Comment: Those are the files that are listed in the image that you shared. I couldn't find them. I deleted the entire Unity Purchasing folder and no use.